# UTC or local time with zone offset for my schema?

Tags: java, soap, xsd, timezone, utc

I am defining a schema for my web service that will be accessed from multiple countries. I am wondering **which of the below 2 should be used** (both are valid according to xsd dateTime type and ISO 8601) and **which one of them is WS-I compliant**?

1. **UTC** format like 14:15Z or 14:15:00Z. The appended Z letter indicates that the time is represented in UTC.
2. Alternatively, use a **local time with explicit zone designation** in one of the formats [+/-]hh:mm. Example: 12:15+02:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somewhat subjective - both are OK. I prefer UTC. You likely need to convert the time to client local anyway (and you should rely on information from the client to do so, since the user may login from different timezones). When storing in UTC, you have to worry less about the details of how storage is taking place, since all times are represented in the same timezone and it is much easier to compare (and thus sort).

Comment: +1 can you please elaborate on "storing in UTC at least makes comparing two datetimes faster"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case.  Sometimes it's useful to know the timezone the client is in.  If the user enters a time of 13:00 in their timezone, they probably still want to see 13:00 when the retrieve the date.

Note, I'm not saying you store the time in local (which would be very bad of course), just that you may want to maintain the timezone.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms compy with WS-I Basic Profile, as they are both valid lexical formats for xsd:dateTime.

Normally, a service description would specify xsd:dateTime in the schema and would not typically constrain the lexical format further. In this case the service implementation should be prepared to handle any valid xsd:dateTime value i.e. should be able to cope with either form in data received from clients.

If you really want to, you could restrict the allowed lexical formats in the schema for your service description, by defining a custom type based on xsd:dateTime with an additional pattern facet. This would still be WS-I Basic profile compliant, I believe, but I would avoid doing this unless you have a very compelling reason. In my experience custom types based on XSD types with added pattern facets do not always play nicely with all XML toolsets, so you may create problems for clients by adding additional constraints beyond xsd:dateTime.